# Change the default generic closing with custom comment text for moderators

Tags: feature-request, moderators, close-dialog, custom-close-reasons

When voting to close a question and choosing the custom comment option, you're given a text field in which to write your reason(s). In the Web interface, that field includes the helpful default text:

> I'm **voting to close** this question because

...and one can simply complete the sentence.

When used by a moderator, though, that language seems a little off. A moderator's vote is **binding and immediate**. While technically correct, I think it would better represent reality if for diamond moderators, the default text was:

> I'm **closing** this question because

Comment: Oh definitely. I do this all the time manually, if I remember to do it at least.

Comment: Yep - I usually delete the whole sentence and write whatever my reason is.